# Looking For A Scalable PubSub Solution Or Alternative

Tags: performance, xmpp, message, scalability, publish-subscribe

I'm currently looking for the best architecture for an IM app I'm trying to build.

The app consists of channels each having a couple thousands of subscribed users. Each user is subscribed only to one channel at a time and is able to publish and read from that channel. Users may move rapidly between channels.

I initially considered using the XMPP PubSub (via Ejabbered or MongooseIM) but as far as I understand it was added as an afterthought and is not very scalable.
I also thought about using using a message queue protocol like AMPQ but I'm not sure if that's what I'm looking for from the IM aspect.

Is my concern regarding the XMPP PubSub justified? And if so, do you know of a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Redis](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) and [Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/). Both are scalable and performant.

Answer (score 0):

I imagined below primary usecases for above IM application based on your inputs.

**

- Usecases

**

1. Many new users keep registering with system and subscribing to one
   of the channels
2. Many existing users changing their subscription from one channel to
   other channel
3. Many existing users keep publishing messages to channels
4. Many existing users keep receiving messages as subscribers

XMPP is natural fit for **3rd and 4th usecases**. "ejabbered" is one of proven highly scalable platform to go ahead.

In case **2nd usecase**, You probably may have logic some thing like this.
 - a)update channel info of the user in DB 
 - b)make him listen to new channel
 - c)change his publishing topic to other channel...so on

When ever you need to do multiple operations, I strongly recommend to use "KAFKA" to perform above operations in async manner

In case of **1st usecase**, Provide registration through rest APIs.So that registration can be done from any device.While registering an user,You may have many operations as follows.
 - 1) register user in DB 
 - 2) create internally IM account
 - 3) send email OR SMS for confirmation...so on

Here also perform 1st operation as a part of rest API service logic. Perform 2nd and 3rd operations in async manner using KAFKA. That means your service logic perform 1st operation in sync manner and raise an event to KAFKA. Every consumer will handle 2nd and 3rd operations in async manner.

System could scale well if all layers/subsystems can scale well. In that perspective, Below tech stack  may help you scale well.

**REST APIS + KAFKA + EJABBERED(XMPP)**